# How do I get a list combining all items from two other lists?

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

I have:

- list1: `[1,2,3]`
- list2: `[3,4,5]`

How can I get a list that combines all these elements (`[1,2,3,3,4,5]`)?

`List.union()` returns a set, thus I will lose one '3'.

`List.zip()` combines it into pairs.

I can do it manually, by creating a new list, but there must be a simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like following :

```
val finalList = firstList + secondList
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `plus` operator:

```
val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = listOf(3, 4, 5)

val combined = list1 + list2 // [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```